# Optimizing UITableView backed by NSFetcchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I recently switched my CoreData backed `UITableView`s to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` instead of an `NSArray`. For one of the tables, scrolling is now very slow, and I think I know why, but I don't know yet what would be the best solution to fix this.

There are two entities `Book` and `Author` which are in a many-to-many relationship. Each cell displays the book title, plus the author. If there is more than one author, it will just display the main author. Each `Author` has an "order" attribute, which is set when the data is imported.

What I have been doing so far is every time the author name is accessed, my `Book` class returns a mainAuthor property (an `NSString`):

```
- (NSString *) mainAuthor
{
    if (!mainAuthor)
    {
       NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"order" ascending: YES];
       NSArray *authorsSorted = [self.authors sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[sortOrder]];

       Author *a = authorsSorted[0];
       mainAuthor = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", a.name];
    }

    return mainAuthor;
}
```

For whatever reason this is now called many times instead of only once and causing the slow down. Maybe `NSFetchedResultsController` fetches the references over and over when scrolling the table?

So how can I fix this? One possibility is to make `mainAuthor` an attribute instead of a property. So it is set immediately when the data is imported. But before I start messing with my dataModel I'd like to know if this would be the way to move forward, or maybe there is an alternative solution?

UPDATE 1: Here is the code where I set up the fetchController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{    
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName: @"Book"];

// sort the books by publishing date
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"date" ascending: YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: @[sort]];

// only get the books that belong to the library of the current viewController
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"libraries contains[cd] %@", self.library];
[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];

[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: @[@"authors"]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize: 10];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest
                                                                      managedObjectContext: moc
                                                                        sectionNameKeyPath: nil
                                                                                 cacheName: nil];

frc.delegate = self;

_fetchedResultsController = frc;

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Post your fetch function, it should not be in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  It should be in a one time call function.  Put a breakpoint in this function and look at the stack trace each time it gets called.  If it is called from multiple places then you have a problem, if it is called from a single place multiple times then you are reloading your data too often.

Comment: Showing us the function that gets called too many times doesn't help.  We need to see what calls it too many times.

Comment: I have no access to my Mac right now so cannot post more code. I do can tell that my fetch function is called from within `viewDidLoad`. I also can tell that the accessor to `mainAuthor` is called many times (eg to calculate the size for the string to set the cell height). More later...

Comment: As an aside, assuming that the `name` attribute is an `NSString *`, you can replace `mainAuthor = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", a.name];` with `mainAuthor = a.name`.

Comment: Alright, I did some more testing, and from using Instruments, it looks like most time is spent in `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`, which is called from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. It is only called once for each cell in the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code I'd assume that `mainAuthor` is not in your Core Data schema. As Core Data handles the lifetime (faulting) of your managed objects you should add this property to your `Book` entity to avoid unpredictable results by using a transient attribute.

Despite this I'd recommend to return an `Author` object instead of a `NSString` as you might change name of the attribute in the future or want to use additional information of the `mainAuthor` in your UI.

**Transient Attribute**

Add a transient attribute `mainAuthor` to your `Book`'s entity and add a custom accessor to your `Book`'s class:

```
- (Author *)mainAuthor
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"mainAuthor"];
    Author *value = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"mainAuthor"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"mainAuthor"];

    if (value == nil)
    {
        NSPredicate *filterByMinOrder = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order == %@.@min.order", self.authors];
        value = [[self.authors filteredSetUsingPredicate:filterByMinOrder] anyObject];
        [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"mainAuthor"];
    }

    return value;
}
```

The disadvantage of using a transient is that *you* have to make sure that the data is always up-to-date during the lifetime of the appropriate `book`. So you have to reset `mainAuthor` in:

- `willTurnIntoFault`
- `awakeFromFetch`
- `awakeFromSnapshotEvents:`

*(Optional, but necessary if the user can change the data)*

- `addAuthorObject:`
- `removeAuthorObject:`

by calling `[self setPrimitiveValue:nil forKey:@"mainAuthor"]`.

*Hint:* Better and faster is to create a synthesized `primitiveMainAuthor` instead of using `primitiveValue:forKey:`: [Managed Object Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdAccessorMethods.html)

---

### Update

Have you tried to set a `fetchBatchSize` in your `NSFetchedResultsController`'s `fetchRequest`?  [Docs: NSFetchRequest fetchBatchSize](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchBatchSize)

---

### Update 2

Yes, setting the appropriate relationship in `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` is necessary in that case.

To identify bottlenecks it's also really helpful to set the debug argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to see the SQL statements created by Core Data. This also often helps to understand the different `NSFetchRequest` attributes and their impacts.

Comment: This looks like a good approach. One question, what is "min.display" ? I get a runtime error: 'Unable to parse the format string "min.display"'

Comment: I guess I get that error because the property order (display in your example) is an NSString. I tried `@"@min.order.integerValue"`, but got the same runtime error. How do I change the NSPredicate to make that work?

Comment: Sorry, I've copied a wrong predicate from one of my projects. I've updated my sample code.

Comment: Yes, it works now, thanks for the correction. Unfortunately, the bottleneck is still the line where self.authors is accessed.  I wonder if it has to do with the fact that the authors at this point have not been loaded into memory yet?

Comment: See my update code above where I added how I set up my FRC. I've played with the batchSize, but so far it is not improving anything.

Comment: I got a nice speed improve by adding `[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: @[@"authors"]];` It still requires a few hundred ms to load the tableView, but it was a few thousand ms before.

Comment: I have updated my code above, which now gives me to smoothest scrolling: using `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:`, a `batchSize` of 10, and the cache set to nil.